# How to use Pandoc --resource-path to merge multiple latex files

Tags: pandoc

I have Pandoc exe kept at X location and my input files are in Y location.

Now I have set of latex files with main latex file which have reference of other latex files.

example :

main latex file contains

```
\input{abstract}

\input{introduction}
```

here abstract and introduction are latex files

now when I try to convert latex to docx, Pandoc is showing "CouldNotLoadIncludeFile"

my command is:

```
inputFilePath + " -o " + outputFileFullPath + " --resource-path=" + completePathOfOtherLatexFile + " --log " + logFilePath;
```

Also if I kept these files in working dir where Pandoc exe is present then it is merging those files.

The problem is Pandoc is not able to look for current dir where my files are.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot (yet) comment to clarify, I'll try to answer on what I understand..

I'm not sure from which environment you are executing your command (which you appear to build from variables), but what I would try first is (the equivalent of):

`cd mylatexdir && pandoc -i inputfile.tex -o outputfile`

For this, pandoc must be in your path. If the main file and the included files are in different dirs, it could make sense to include the `--resource-path` again, otherwise I think it doesn't do anything (assuming you have no other includes or images in the latex files).

Alternatively you can also do (if pandoc not in your path):

`cd mylatexdir && /path/to/pandoc -i inputfile.tex -o outputfile`

HTH,